# .htaccess-File redirect to same prefix

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess` file with the intention of redirecting all requests to `example.com` to `http://www.example.com/something:`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

However, the redirection is only redirecting to `www.example.com` without the `/something` part. I have attempted various solutions, but none have been successful. Could it be possible that the browser is not displaying the `http://` part, causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, absolutely right, some browser try to be "smart" in that way and hide the protocol scheme in a URL.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly didn't work

Comment: Your RewriteRule seems to be ok. Try **RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$** for the RewriteCond statement.